# How can I modify my code to include loop?

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to create a function that examines how variables with different distributions influence OLS results. I have created two DVs (y1 and y2) but would like to expand this to include five or so. I am trying to change my code to include a loop so I do not have to copy and paste this multiple times, but I am not having much luck. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
library(psych)
library(arm)
library(plyr)
library(fBasics)

regsim <- function(iter, n) {
ek1 <- rnorm(n, 0, 1) 
ek2 <- rnorm(n, 0, 5) 
x <- rnorm(n, 0, .5)

y1 <- .3*x + ek1
y2 <- .3*x + ek2

#y1
lm1 <- lm(y1 ~ x)
bhat1 <- coef (lm1)[2]
sehat1 <- se.coef (lm1) [2] 
skewy1 <- skew(y1)
stdevy1 <- stdev(y1)

#y2
lm2 <- lm(y2 ~ x)
bhat2 <- coef (lm2)[2]
sehat2 <- se.coef (lm2) [2] 
skewy2 <- skew(y2)
stdevy2 <- stdev(y2)


results <- c(bhat1, sehat1, stdevy1, skewy1,
         bhat2, sehat2, stdevy2, skewy2)
names(results) <- c('b1', 'se1', 'sdy1', 'skewy1',
                'b2', 'se2', 'sdy2', 'skewy2')
return(results)
}


iter <-1000
n <-500


results <- NULL
sims <-ldply(1:iter, regsim, n)
sims$n <- n
results <- rbind(results, sims)
```

Comment: Is x always the predictor variable ie always "constant"?

Comment: You define `function(iter, n)` but `iter` is never used. What is `iter`?

Comment: your `ek` vectors take different 3rd arguments, if we put it in a loop, how do you want to provide to the function the values to use? By passing a vector of values?

Comment: Functions `skew`, `se.coef` and `stdev` are not base functions. What are the packages that you are using? Tip: it's *not* package `plyr`.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the complete code. Now I show the role of iter.

Comment: Yes, x is always the predictor.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```r
n <- 1000
x <- rnorm(n, 0, .5)

fun_reg <- function(n, ek_mu, ek_sd, x){
  s <- list() # list to collect results for output
  ek <- rnorm(n, ek_mu, ek_sd) 

  y <- .3*x + ek

  m <- lm(y ~ x)
  s$bhat <- coef(m)[2]
  s$sehat <- arm::se.coef(m)[2] 
  s$skewy <- psych::skew(y)
  s$stdevy <- fBasics::stdev(y)
  return(s)
}

purrr::map_dfr(c(1, 5, 10, 20, 50), ~fun_reg(n, 0, ., x))
```

**Edit:**

This now has 500 observations each and the regression is repeated with 1000 draws for each value of the standard deviation. A variable `ek_sd` has been added to the final output, to reflect with which standard deviation the values were arrived at. Note that x is not redrawn for each iteration, but I'm not entirely sure, that that is what you want. If you want x to be redrawn at each iteration, move it inside the function.

```r
n <- 500
x <- rnorm(n, 0, .5)

fun_reg <- function(n, ek_mu, ek_sd, x){
  s <- list()
  ek <- rnorm(n, ek_mu, ek_sd) 

  y <- .3*x + ek

  m <- lm(y ~ x)
  s$ek_sd <- ek_sd
  s$bhat <- coef(m)[2]
  s$sehat <- arm::se.coef(m)[2] 
  s$skewy <- psych::skew(y)
  s$stdevy <- fBasics::stdev(y)
  return(s)
}

intr <- unlist(lapply(c(1, 5, 10, 20, 50), rep, 1000))

purrr::map_dfr(intr, ~fun_reg(n, 0, ., x))
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. However, does this include 1,000 iterations for each condition? Specifically, I would like each dataset to include 500 observations, and then I would like to run the regression 1,000 times.

Comment: You can set the number of observations by changing n, which I set to 1000 at the beginning of the script. The first argument of `purrr::map_dfr()` are the values for the standard deviation of `ek` with which each iteration is run. Each line in the resulting dataframe represents one of the regressions. But what do you want to change in each of the 1000 runs of the regression?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I am trying to create 1,000 iterations for each one of the standard deviation conditions (so I can average them later). So, I need 1,000 simulated datasets, each with 500 observations.

Answer (score 0):

Another option...

```r
regsim <- function(n=100,num.y=5,sd=c(1:5)){
  if(length(sd) != num.y){stop('length of sd must match number of dependent vars')
  } else {
    ldply(1:num.y,function(x){
      e <- rnorm(n,0,sd=sd[x])
      x <- rnorm(n,0,5)
      y <- 0.3*x + e
      out <- lm(y~x)
      b1 <- coef(out)[2]
      int <- coef(out)[1]
      data.frame(b1=b1,int=int)
    })
    }
  }

regsim(num.y=10,sd=c(1:10))

            b1        int
1   0.30817303  0.0781049
2   0.38681600 -0.3359067
3   0.24560773 -0.0277561
4   0.08032659  0.1877233
5   0.39873955 -0.6027522
6   0.21729930  0.7384340
7   0.33761456 -0.1053028
8   0.26502006 -0.1851552
9   0.15452261 -1.6334873
10 -0.10496863 -0.3225169
```

This will allow you to specify the number of dependent variables and the SD for each error term. You can then use `replicate` to repeat the function for the desired number of replications.

```r
replicate(10,regsim(),simplify = F)

[[1]]
         b1         int
1 0.3047779 -0.01984306
2 0.3133198 -0.20458410
3 0.2833979 -0.25307502
4 0.3066878 -0.03235019
5 0.1374949  0.10958616

[[2]]
         b1         int
1 0.2902103 -0.12683502
2 0.3499006  0.06691437
3 0.1949797 -0.14371830
4 0.2358269  0.53117467
5 0.2869511  0.16281380

[[3]]
         b1         int
1 0.2952211  0.05905549
2 0.2367774  0.02862166
3 0.0896778 -0.08467935
4 0.2352622 -0.20835837
5 0.3149963  0.07042032

[[4]]
         b1         int
1 0.2946468 -0.08266406
2 0.3322577  0.17558135
3 0.2200087 -0.25778150
4 0.1822915  0.34962679
5 0.2442479  0.34433656

[[5]]
         b1         int
1 0.2882853  0.12677506
2 0.3455534 -0.27885958
3 0.2981193  0.04598347
4 0.3380173  0.05243198
5 0.2148643 -0.09631672

[[6]]
         b1         int
1 0.2962269  0.03743759
2 0.2979327 -0.12830803
3 0.3352781 -0.03935422
4 0.2584965 -0.05924351
5 0.2856802  0.03430055

[[7]]
         b1         int
1 0.2968077 -0.10300109
2 0.2954560  0.25979902
3 0.3276077 -0.07001758
4 0.1825841  0.13508932
5 0.4302788 -0.13951914

[[8]]
         b1         int
1 0.2992147  0.02084806
2 0.2765976  0.07277813
3 0.2469616  0.44580403
4 0.2601966 -0.09849855
5 0.2679183  0.50501652

[[9]]
         b1         int
1 0.2963905  0.03308366
2 0.3356783 -0.06080088
3 0.3199835  0.22533444
4 0.3546083 -0.26909478
5 0.3536241 -0.19795094

[[10]]
         b1         int
1 0.3100336 -0.05228032
2 0.4076447 -0.18715063
3 0.3436858 -0.37518649
4 0.4569368 -0.09114672
5 0.3255668 -0.18738138
```

Comment: Thank you. This answers (I think) my question. I tried to ask the question very simply, but my problem is more complex. I would like to include error terms with different distributions (i.e., non-normal) altogether. So I am not altering just the SD but also the distributions (some of which have up to five parameters). I am not sure this will generalize to other situations, but it indeed answers my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This reduces the package reliance to just `psych::skew` and an optional `ggplot2` call:

```
library(psych)

regsim <- function(n, eks) {
  x <- rnorm(n, 0, .5)
  ek <- sapply(eks, function(x) rnorm(n, 0, x))
  y <- 0.3 * x + ek

  lms <- lm(y ~ x)

  data.frame(b_hat = lms[['coefficients']][2,],
             int = lms[['coefficients']][1, ],
             skew_y = psych::skew(y),
             se_hat = unlist(lapply(summary(lms), function(lst) lst[[4]][2,2]), use.names = FALSE),
             sd_y = apply(y, 2, sd),
             sd_eks = eks
             )
}

iter <-1000
n <-500

eks_sd = c(1,5)

# do the simulations and make them into a nice data.frame
sims <- replicate(iter, regsim(n, eks_sd), simplify = FALSE)
results <- do.call(rbind, sims)

#next parts are optional
results$iter_id <- rep(seq_len(iter), each = length(eks_sd))
tibble::as_tibble(results)

# Random graph because everyone loves graphs
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(results, aes(x = iter_id, y = int)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(vars(sd_eks))
```

The main thing is that `lm` can take multiple `y` arguments. That's why we we create a matrix of `ek` using `sapply`.

[image]